# Embedded Systems Podcasts

Tags: embedded, podcast

Are there any good podcasts focused on discussing issues of particular relevance to the development of embedded systems?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is more towards the EE side of embedded (I'm one of those guys with a foot in each camp, firmware & hardware), but David L. Jones has an ["Electronics Engineering Video Blog Podcast"](http://www.alternatezone.com/eevblog/) which is informative and entertaining.